# Allow zooming beond lvl. 22 in a Google Map

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, zooming, indoor-positioning-system

I'm trying to overlay a building floor-plan on a google map. However zoom level 21 is too small to show indoor detail. I need zoom 23-26.

I tried settings like:

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom : 24,
            maxZoom: 26,
    center : new google.maps.LatLng(52.226071,20.950115),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
};
```

but it does not work. I get the default behavior.

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom : 22
            maxZoom: 26,
            minZoom: 22,
    center : new google.maps.LatLng(52.226071,20.950115),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
};
```

This, does force more zoom, but i can't get beyond 22.

Surely there has to be some solution for floor-plan overlaying on a map.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `maxZoom` for the built-in mapTypes is predefined(depending on the mapType and the location)

**What you can do:**
Use a [custom mapType](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#CustomMapTypes) (you may define a maxZoom for it that fit's your requirements)

Observe the zoom_changed-event of the map. When to zoom reaches the `maxZoom` for the particular location(21 in this case) switch from the built-in mapType to your custom mapType(and switch back when the zoom goes below 21).

Comment: I think this solves my problem. I would be cool if the surroundings of my floor plan weren't blank (my custom maptype loads blank tiles), but rather zoomed satellite tiles, but still this is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working (albeit with a few bugs) by using a modified version of https://github.com/tilemapjp/ZoomTMSLayer. Instead of using my own tile map service, I just used the same urls that Google was making network calls to.

Essentially you extend google.maps.ImageMapType and redefined the getTile() and getTileUrl() methods. For any zoom level greater than the max zoom level supported by Google at that location, grab the tile that Google would have returned at the max zoom, then scale it and transform each tile so that they line up.

I put my code on Github for viewing convenience: https://github.com/dallinski/GoogleMapsSuperZoomMapType

Comment: I seem to have come upon the bugs mentioned, since when using I often get empty tiles on the left side when panning.  I don't have the expertise to diagnose those, any help fixing them would be appreciated.

Comment: I actually ironed out most of the bugs. Here's my code: https://github.com/dallinski/GoogleMapsSuperZoomMapType.

Comment: Took me awhile to figure out the "ts" extension, but I now understand that requires use and familiarity with Type Script.  Hopefully it will be useful to another reader.